# Multiple Worksheet in phpExcel

Tags: php, file, loops

actualy this for saving huge data to excel file, but excel have limitation for storing data for each row, i wanna make a few sheet acording to data row, here is the problem, say that i have 1000 data in database, and i wanna make it splited by 500 for each and put in to first sheet, how do we make that happen ?, i have tried with following code

```
$this->load->library('excel');
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','NAME');
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++){
    if($i>=500){
      #save first 500 data to first sheet and then continue for the rest to 2nd sheet
    }
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue("A$i",$i);
}
```

i wanna make for each sheet saved 500 data, is it possible to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Basically something like this:

```
$inserted = 0;
for(...) {
    $inserted++;
    if ($inserted % 500 == 0) {
       start new sheet
    }
}
```

keep a counter. whenever the counter reaches a multiple of 500, start a new sheet, and start inserting into that.

Comment: i have tried that but each sheet stil stored 1000 data, i guest the problem with `$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);` i have tried with `$this->excel->createSheet();` but not working either

Comment: yes, but since you only write the active sheet, you'd have to make your NEW sheets the active ones as well...

Comment: how do i do that? is using `$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);` or there is another way with using `createSheet()`